# Как прочитать строку из ответа сервера в bat

Tags: cmd, bat

Всем привет! Вопрос такой : как прочитать сообщение из строки и назначить этим значением переменную? Мне надо выполнить на удаленной машине sudo kill -9 ****, где **** - номер процесса, который я получаю из предыдущей команды pgrep, сервер отвечает, например "5555".
Как создать переменную, которая будет читать этот ответ "5555"? Переменная, чтобы потом её вложить в одну команду *"sudo kill -9 varNumber"*
Буду очень признателен за ответ

Comment: bat или bash скрипте? Ваша задача проста - `PID=$(pgrep XXXXX)` (возле символа равно нет пробелов, это очень важно. А дальше `sudo kill -9 $PID`

Comment: `FOR /F ["ключи"] %переменная IN (набор-файлов) DO команда [параметры]`. Подробности - `FOR /?`

Comment: в bat, подключаюсь к удаленному компьютеру, на котором ОС Ubuntu, потому так сложно

Comment: покажите чуточку больше. как подключаетесь, как выполняете, потому что сейчас слишком много вариантов. Хотя может вам выполнять `pkill -9 XXXX`, которая сразу две команды в одной сделает

Comment: Первый вариант сработал, благодарю) подключение было через ssh, к удаленному компьютеру

Comment: Ну тогда не важно, с под чего запускается, с батника или сторонней программы (Putty).